# Woocommerce Mini Cart - How to show prices excluding tax

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

my woocommerce mini cart shows the product price including tax by default. (the prices are shown excluding the tax all over the website) I'd like to show the prices excluding tax on mini cart, but keep showing them including tax in the main cart page. I believe it can be achieved with a hook but I wasn't able to do it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woocommerce provides two function `wc_get_price_excluding_tax` and `wc_get_price_including_tax` that you can use to display the product with or without tax.

What you might need to do is update your cart template file to use `wc_get_price_excluding_tax` to display the item price.

You can look at how these functions are implemented here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_price_including_tax.html.

One thing to note that these function take a WC_Product object `product` as their first parameter, so you might need to get the product from the cart item first. You can do it by using `wc_get_product`. An example:

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

    // Display the price here
    echo wc_get_price_excluding_tax($product);
}
```